# Disable untitled editor improvement - first line name in the title

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

Is there any to revert/disable the newest change for the untitled tab name (https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_42#_untitled-editor-improvements)

I would prefer to the untitled-1 than the first sentence line.

Comment: What if you leave the first line empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your link says:

> Note: If the first line is empty or does not contain any words, the
>   title will fall back to Untitled-* as before.

I don't think there is a way to disable it other than to have that first line blank until you do give it a name.

The request for a setting to disable the current functionality is tracked here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90378 (Config to limit/disable the new Untitled tab auto-naming) or https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90495

you could upvote that issue.

----------  update, coming in v1.43:

> A new setting `workbench.editor.untitled.labelFormat` lets you control
>   whether untitled editors should use the file contents as the title or
>   not. Possible values are content or name. Configure
>   `'workbench.editor.untitled.labelFormat': 'name'` for the previous
>   behavior, where untitled editors would have a short title, such as
>   Untitled-1.
>
> When pasting text into an untitled editor, VS Code now automatically
>   tries to detect the language mode from the first line of text. For
>   example, pasting XML will set the XML mode automatically upon paste if
>   the first line contains the typical XML header .